# Does storing strings in Strings.xml vs code make reverse engineering more tedious?

Tags: android, xml, string

Can someone who's reverse engineering an app easily/automatically replace the getString(R....) calls with the corresponding string value stored in Strings.xml? I'm pretty sure the answer is yes considering even Android Studio will hint the content of the Strings.xml over getString(R...) calls.

The reason I'm asking is I'm wondering if storing strings with random names in an xml resource file offers any "security" benefits over simply having them hard coded in the code. I'm aware that using Strings.xml allows translating etc which I am not interested in.

The app is completely standalone and does not fetch data from a server, so I can't hide anything outside of the client.

Even though my code is obfuscated, I don't want to give away too much of the logic and context by allowing someone to simply read messages throughout the code (or linked to Strings.xml).

I know that it's impossible to stop a determined person from reverse engineering an app, but if there are simple things I can do to make it less appealing, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't. One of the reliable ways in which you can hide your Strings is by encoding and decoding. It is well explained [here](https://rammic.github.io/2015/07/28/hiding-secrets-in-android-apps/).